# Using role-based authentication in ASP.NET Core is ok with using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC. In my project I use Ajax in order to get some JSON data from an action on my controller. It requests data from the database, then return it as json. It works well.

I want to use role-based authentication in my ASP.NET Core MVC project.

This is my question: if I use a controller action restriction by something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`, will it allow anyone whose role is "Admin" to call this method? (I mean will it work without any other trouble just by logging in as Admin)

And will it disable accessing those data when the role is not "Admin"`?

I have not still add Identification to my new project and I'm new to using Ajax.

Comment: you got the right idea, it will only allow the user with the role Admin

Comment: You got mixed up: **authentication** is checking **who you are** - by means of a log in, password, etc. You cannot have "role-based authentication" .... what you have is role-based **authorization** - the process (after authentication) deciding - based on who you are -whether or not you're allowed to do something - or not.

Comment: `will it allow anyone who his role is Admin by this method (I mean will it work without any other trouble just by logging in as Admin) and will it disable accessing those data when the role is not Admin.`Yes.And when you login in,it will add a cookie value.

Comment: @marc_s uh. My mistake. Yes you are right and I meant that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested it and it does as desired. It return `401 Unauthorized` status code when the user is not authorized and `200 OK` success status response code. Thanks guys for your responses.